# MS Office Add On

Tags: vba, ms-office

I want to add on certain feature in MS Office. Currently, I am looking at VBA to develop it. However, it seems that running macros requires security disabled. This means that if I distribute the VBA program, other people need to enable macros to run. (Security issues)

The problem now is, how do I distribute the VBA that I wrote? E.g. in a .exe file? And is there any other method to go about creating this add on?

I downloaded some add on for MS Word and it seems that it is written in C++ and it is in .dll format.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can run macros in a document/template/add-in even in "high" security mode, if:

- the VBA project is digitally signed
- the user agrees to 'trust' the publisher of the digital signature

The first time the user runs a macro signed with your digital signature, they'll get a prompt saying "the macros are signed by YourCompanyName - do you want to trust all add-ins from this publisher". If they click "yes", they won't see the prompt again - and your macros will run.

See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa141471(office.10).aspx) for details of how to create a digital signature.

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Studio Tools for Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsto/default.aspx) (VSTO) allows you to author extensions to Microsoft Office using any .NET language, including Visual C++. Such extensions would indeed compile to DLL-files, and after installation on a client machine, they wouldn't require the user to dismiss any additional security warnings. You will need Visual Studio 2005/2008 Professional in order to use the VSTO framework.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Tools_for_Office) has more information about VSTO, including a comparison with VBA. [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_ss_gw?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=vsto) seems to have a fair amount of books on the subject as well.

Comment: If I were to use VSTO, do I still need to have a digital signature in the program?

Comment: VSTO is getting there, but it's still *much* harder than developing in VBA.

Comment: And slower.... http://www.codematic.net/Excel-development/Excel-Visual-studio/visual-studio-excel.htm recons 10x than VBA and 20x C++

But since it is the future, it's worth considering :) I know my VBA toolkit is mostly made of things i wrote in the last 10 years.